# Woocommerce remove menu item on myaccount dashboard

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm doing a redesign of the woocommerce dashboard.

I had copy the dashboard.php from woocommerce folder to my theme folder.

So now I want to get rid of the side menu from dashboard only(Remain on other pages eg. account detail page)

[image]

Tried this code in dashboard.php, doesn't work.

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'remove_my_account_links' );
function remove_my_account_links( $menu_links ){

    unset( $menu_links['edit-address'] );


    return $menu_links;

}
```

Understand this should be in function.php, but I only want to remove it from dashboard. How should I do that?

Comment: You need to place this snippet in your child theme's functions.php

Comment: @Akshat The problem is it will remove the menu item on all my account pages, but I just need that to be remove on dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone I have solved this..

On myaccount.php remove

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation' );
```

also remove if you want your content to be on the center of pages

```
<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content"></div>
```

then, on my-order.php, edit-address.php etc add in above code in the correct position, then upload to your theme folder so any update of woocommerce won't override this change

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `dashboard.php` template by copying it over to `/your-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/dashboard.php`.

From there it should be easy to customize it to your needs.

Comment: Did that, but doesn't work.